# Import Variables From One File Into Another

Tags: python, variables, import, automation, program-entry-point

I am attempting to import several variables from one file into another file, without running the first file twice.  Specifically, I have a script called "run_all_files.py" which loops through files in a local directory to be run in sequence, and this is the script through which I want to execute the files in question.  In the file "file_1.py", I want to `import` the variables `A` and `B` into "file_2.py" but I do not want "file_1.py" to re-run.

I have also attempted to invoke `if __name__=='__main__':` function, but cannot get variables `A` and `B` to `import` by themselves, and "file_1.py" still runs twice.  Both "file_1.py" and "file_2.py" are located in the `path` listed and are executed when running "run_all_files.py".

"run_all_files.py"

```
import os
path = "C:\\users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\"
def run_the_files():

    file_list = ['file_1.py', 'file_2.py']
    for filename in file_list:
        os.system('python' + ' ' + os.path.join(path,filename))

run_the_files()
```

"file_1.py"

```
import os
def run_first_file():

    global A, B
    A = 'Hello'
    B = 'User'
    C = 'Python Programmer'
    print("This is the first file to run")

run_first_file()
```

"file_2.py"

```
import os
from file_1 import A,B

def run_second_file():

    print('Welcome, and ', A + ' ' + B) 
    print("This second program runs smoothly")

run_second_file()
```

Current output:

```
This is the first file to run
This is the first file to run
Welcome, and  Hello User
This second program runs smoothly
```

Desired output:

```
This is the first file to run
Welcome, and  Hello User
This second program runs smoothly
```

** Update: Change file_list in "run_all_files.py" to file_list = ['file_2.py'] to achieve the desired output **

Comment: The variables `A` and `B` are _local_ to the `run_first_file()` function in "file_1.py" — in other words, they are not module-level variables.

Comment: martineau - Is it still possible to import these variables into file_2.py? From what I've read, I should still be able to import them from the file_1.py but you are correct about these variables being local to file_1.py. Is there still a way to invoke "if__name__=='__main__' or import the variables via a class? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to `import` a function's local variables.

Comment: The code in your question had a several typos unrelated to what you are asking and couldn't possibly run.

Comment: You could `import` the variables if you declared them `global A, B` at the beginning of the `run_first_file()` function in the "file_1.py" script (after fixing the other syntax errors and typographical errors in your posted code). This will prevent them from becoming local variables.

Comment: martineau - Thanks for the suggestion, it seems to have solved my problem of running the "file_1.py" file twice, but it still does not recognize these variables in "file_2.py".  Do I also need to declare "global A,B" at the start of the "run_second_file" function?  I tried this technique, and also leaving file_2.py as is (only declaring "global A,B" in file_1.py) and received the same "NameError: name __ is not defined" error.

Comment: I'm not sure what code you're talking about. Please fix the problems with the code in your question so it matches what you're running. Note especially that there's no `run_first_file()` function defined in your "file_2.py" script so it can't be called.

Comment: martineau - I guess this is where my confusion is.  The point of my question is to determine how to import variables or functions from file_1.py into the file_2.py without having to re-run file.py (after initial execution).  Per my understanding, variable "A" from file_1.py can be imported into file_2.py via "from file_1 import A", but this causes file_1.py to be re-run altogether.  I cannot determine how to rectify this, but the above scripts do work on my end, other than file_1.py running twice.  Thanks again for your insights. :)

Comment: In the updated code, "file_2.py" will not produce the output you claim you're getting — especially the `Welcome, and  Hello User` — since the `from file_1 import A,B` will fail for the reasons I mentioned earlier about `A` and `B` being local variables. You can fix that by declaring them `global`. When "file_2.py" is executed, the `from file_1 import A,B` causes "file_.py" to be executed. The fact that "run_all_files.py" ran it previously doesn't matter — thus there is no way to avoid it running twice with the code you have (even if you "fix" the importation with the `global` declaration).

Comment: martineau - I added the "global A, B" declaration in "file_1.py", and I am still getting the "current output" as shown in my original post.  What would you suggest as the fix to correctly import variables A and B from file_1.py into file_2.py?  Should I construct a class?  I would think it should be fairly simple from this script, but I am missing something conceptually.  Thanks again!

Comment: What you're missing is that the fact that even though the "run_all_files.py" script already ran "file_1.py" it has no affect on how "file_2.py" runs later. This is because each is executed by a _separate_ invocation of the Python interpreter so each is an independent process. I know of no way to "get variables A and B to import by themselves". Python's `import` statement causes the corresponding module to be executed (by the same invocation of the interpreter). The results are cached so that if it is ever `import`ed again by _that_ invocation, the cached version is used and it isn't run again.

Comment: martineau - Thank you for the additional clarification, your logic makes sense!  Do you see of any workaround at all?  I've been reviewing other Q&A, I see similar questions/approaches but still can't quite get it to work for my purposes.  I'll keep working at it, thanks again for your help/patience.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. Sounds like you need a way to determine what files in the folder to skip because they're imported by other scripts in the folder. One way might be to establish some sort of file-naming convention. Another would be to put file imported by others in a sub-directory (although that would require changing how they're imported by the upper-level scripts slightly).

Comment: martineau - Per my updated post, including the current/desired outputs, I'm just trying to show that variables A and B from file_1.py can be imported and outputted via a print statement after execution of file_2.py, which is run after file_1.py executes.  These are the only two files in the list of files to be executed per run_all_files.py.   It seems as if it should be fairly straightforward but I am still missing something...will keep working at it!

Comment: My point is that if only run "file_2.py" is run you will get the desired output because it causes "file_1.py" to run when it's `import`ed — so there's not need for "run_all_files.py" to explicitly run "file_1.py' — so I was suggesting generic ways to prevent something like that from happening. This will be my final comment here.

Comment: martineau - Thank you for clarifying, and simplifying your rationale in even more layman's terms...this actually achieves my desired result!  I'll go ahead and update the script and confirm your edits/inputs as the appropriate solution - Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be if you go via a class, is definitely not elegant, but works.

"file_1.py"

```
from var import sol
class v(object):
    sol = 'Hello'
```

"file_2.py"

```
from var import v
print(v.sol)
```